# Converting JSON data from requests.get to a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, json, pandas, python-requests

I am trying to convert a json payload with no keys into a Pandas Dataframe. Below is what I have now

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get("https://api.pro.coinbase.com/products/BTC-USD/candles")

df = pd.read_json(r.json()).columns = ["time", "low", "high", "open", "close", "volume"]

print(df)
```

The request returns a payload like this...

```
[
    [
        1613256660,
        47077.61,
        47103.32,
        47100,
        47084.96,
        1.6661533
    ],
    ...
]
```

Comment: Your code is correct but for some syntax errors - `pd.DataFrame(r.json(), columns = ["time", "low", "high", "open", "close", "volume"])` will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pd.read_json` is used to read JSON string data. In your case, `requests.Response` has already parsed the JSON and is returning a list of lists when you call [`response.json()`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/#requests.Response.json). So it should be sufficient to pass the list structure to `pd.DataFrame` directly:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(response.json(), 
                  columns=["time", "low", "high", "open", "close", "volume"])
```